# Recoding values in R

Tags: r, recode, mutate

I am trying to make the table below show a "Y" if the cell is populated. And if the cell is empty it is recoded as an "N"

Below I have provided a image along with the code I am using. In the image, the left column is what I am working with, and the right column is what I'm wanting it to be recoded as.

[image]

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(column1 = recode(column1,
                               " " = "N",
                               "If populated" = "Y"))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df %>% mutate(column1 = ifelse(column1 == " ", "N", "Y"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if_else()` function from dplyr to create the new column, though the exact syntax depends on what the blank values are actually represented by in your data frame.

```
# If the values are stored as NA:
df <- df |>
  mutate(recode = if_else(is.na(column1), 'n', 'y'))

# If the values are stored as empty strings:
df <- df |>
  mutate(recode = if_else(column1 == '', 'n', 'y'))

# If the values are stored as spaces:
df <- df |>
  mutate(recode = if_else(column1 == ' ', 'n', 'y'))
```

Comment: `ifelse` is not part of `dplyr`

Comment: Whoops! Yes, I was thinking of `if_else`. Updating now